# Find the maximum of the value $|x|+|y|+|z|$

Tags: inequality

> Let $x,y,z\in R$ and satisfy:
>   $$\begin{cases}
> |x+2y-3z|\le 6\\
> |x-2y+3z|\le 6\\
> |x-2y-3z|\le 6\\
> |x+2y+3z|\le 6\\
> \end{cases}$$
>   Find the maximum of the following sum:
>   $$|x|+|y|+|z|.$$

It seems that a use of triangle inequality solves it, but I can't be sure what this maximum equal to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constraints say that $|x| + 2 |y| + 3|z| \leq 6$.
To get the maximum of $|x| + |y| + |z|$ it is then convenient to choose $|x| = 6$, $y = z = 0$.

Comment: why $|x|+2|y|+3|z|\le 6?$ How to get it?

Comment: You have all the combinations of signs of $x$, $y$, $z$, so that one among the four constraints gives $|x| + 2|y| + 3|z| \leq 6$. Once this is satisfied, all the others are satisfied too.

Comment: I can't understand,can you use which inequality to have $|x|+2|y|+3|z|\le 6$

Comment: I know $|x|+2|y|+3|z|$ great any give the LHS inequality

Comment: Assume $x>0$ to fix the ideas. If, for example, $y<0$ and $z>0$, the second inequality gives $|x - 2y + 3z| = |x| + 2 |y| + 3|z|$. You can check that, with any combination of signs, you can always get $|x| + 2|y| + 3|z|$ at l.h.s. of one of the inequalities.